# How to plot 3 columns and 2 rows of images with white spaces?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot 3 columns and 2 rows of images. Below is my code for plotting them but there is a white space. How do I plot images without white space?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(10,10))
for i in range(2):
    ax1, ax2, ax3 = axes[i]
    ax1.imshow(X[i])
    ax1.set_title('Noise Image')
    ax2.imshow(y[i])
    ax2.set_title('Actual Image')
    ax3.imshow(denoised_imgages[i])
    ax3.set_title('OutputImage')
plt.show()
```

Image reference of the output of above code:

[image]

Comment: Chose a different figsize?

Comment: `fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)` will get rid of some of that whitespace, but because imshow forces equal aspect ratio on the axes, some will remain unless you get the figure aspect ratio exactly right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [subplots_adjust()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html).

a quick example:-

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(10,10))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
for i in range(2):
    ax1, ax2, ax3 = axes[i]
    ax1.imshow(X[i])
    ax1.axis('off') # for removing axis
    ax2.axis('off')
    ax3.axis('off')
    ax1.set_title('Noise Image')
    ax2.imshow(y[i])
    ax2.set_title('Actual Image')
    ax3.imshow(denoised_imgages[i])
    ax3.set_title('OutputImage')
plt.show()
```

usage of subplots_adjust:-

`subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)`